# Excel: Huge file very slow with Bloomberg

Tags: excel, api, bloomberg, vba

I have an excel document with like 20 sheets, some of which have like 5,000 rows and 200 columns. There are also like 100 macros, many of which pull data from Bloomberg API. My whole computer is extremely slow because of this and sometimes crashes which is bad because I use the excel document professionally. Are there any libraries/solution/modules/software that is built for this kind of purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the automatic refresh of Bloomberg formulas: In the Bloomberg ribbon, uncheck "Real-Time Updates". When you do want to refresh a certain subset of your Excel file, you can can do so on a per selection, worksheet or workbook basis using the "Refresh Worksheet" button (it has a dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - spreadserve.com was developed for automation and serverization of business critical Excel spreadsheets. It was specifically designed for the trading floor scenario you describe.